# What is the correct way to load modules for iptables on Centos 6

Tags: centos, iptables, centos6, modprobe

Where should I load iptables modules, for example ip_conntrack and ip_conntrack_ftp.

Places I have found that might be candidates, but are they?

- The IPTABLES_MODULES variable in /etc/init.d/iptables
- In /etc/modprobe.conf
- In /etc/modprobe.d/xxxx.conf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of them.

`/etc/rc.d/rc.sysinit` looking for two locations to load modules:

```
# Load other user-defined modules
for file in /etc/sysconfig/modules/*.modules ; do
  [ -x $file ] && $file
done

# Load modules (for backward compatibility with VARs)
if [ -f /etc/rc.modules ]; then
        /etc/rc.modules
fi
```

So, you should put the loading command into `/etc/sysconfig/modules/*.modules` or `/etc/rc.modules`:

```
# echo "modprobe ip_conntrack" >> /etc/sysconfig/modules/iptables.modules
# chmod +x /etc/sysconfig/modules/iptables.modules
```

Comment: Looks like you are answering all my questions. This was the general answer to my question, and @Iain had the answer to the problem I actually tried to solve.

Comment: For ubuntu, how can I do the same ? I need to load ip_nat_pptp module here.

Answer (score 18):

For iptables on CentOS there is an additional location which is where I have those particular modules configured to load and that's the `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config` file. The start of the file looks like this

```
# Load additional iptables modules (nat helpers)
#   Default: -none-
# Space separated list of nat helpers (e.g. 'ip_nat_ftp ip_nat_irc'), which
# are loaded after the firewall rules are applied. Options for the helpers are
# stored in /etc/modprobe.conf.
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack"
```

When I run `service iptables restart` I get this line

```
Loading additional iptables modules: nf_conntrack_ftp nf_co[  OK  ]
```

If I play with the contents of the

```
IPTABLES_MODULES="nf_conntrack_ftp nf_conntrack"
```

above it changes the output of the `Loading additional modules` line when I restart the service.